# Parsec Connection Failure Error -10 and -11

Tags: windows-10

After fresh installing Windows 10, I was not able connect to a Parser Host using another Windows PC.

The error was:

`Error: Client Connection Failure (-10)`

According to the [docs](https://support.parsec.app/hc/en-us/articles/360022720351-All-Error-Codes), this refers to `DECODE_ERR_INIT`

Answer (score 0):

There might be several reasons for these two errors, however the Parsec docs does not give possible solutions.

In my case going to `App & Features` > `Optional Features` > `Add Feature` and then look for `Media Feature Pack` and install it, reboot and should work.

I was able to discover this issue due to Rainway and Dixter failing because a `.dll` was missing regarding this precise feature.